# how to loop through a nested loop so that the main loop and the nested one can go in parallel

Tags: bash, loops, nested

I have two text files, one with patient IDs (subjects.txt) and one with some measures(number_of_slices.txt). Both text files contain 1 column only.

In a third file (.xmlg), I have put specific words (e.g.,number_of_brain_slices) that I want to be automatically substituted for the 1st patients ID with the 1st measure, then the 2nd patients ID and the second measure. However, with the current loop, I am producing these .xmlg files with a different patient_ID but with the same measure (the number of slices) as I don't know how to write the nested loop and make it increase by 1 position every time, so patient and measure go in parallel - second patient - second measure, third patient - third measure etc.
Does anyone know how to do that in bash?

```
#!bin/bash

for sub in `cat subjects.txt`
do 
    for f in `cat number_of_slices.txt`
    do 
    sed -i "s/number_of_brain_slices/${f}/g" \
           /data/mri_measures/analysis/set_files/${sub}.xmlg;
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion using the `paste` command:

```
#! /bin/sh

set -o nounset

WorkDir='/data/mri_measures/analysis/set_files'

paste subjects.txt number_of_slices.txt \
| while read -r ID Measure
  do    File="${WorkDir}/${ID}.xmlg"
        if test -f "$File"
           then sed -i "s/number_of_brain_slices/${Measure}/g" "$File"
        else echo "missing xmlg file for subject \"$ID\"!"
        fi
  done
```

`paste file1 file2` will merge the two files line-wise.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me! I am not sure how to introduce the ID as part of the subjects.txt and Measure as referring to number_of_slices.txt, as currently, it gives me an error that such a directory ".xmlg" does not exist ["No such file or directory"]. In other words, it does not read through the subjects.txt at all.

Comment: Wow, no! Even if there is an error message, I just checked the individual files and they all have different #of slices and thus the correct number of slices!! So, it worked! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! Also, I updated the code so that it checks for the existence of each `.xmlg` file before attempting `sed` substitution. Is it any better?